# Calling private member getter call class destructor every time

Tags: c++, private, getter

I'm working on a C++ project and I encountered this weird behavior.

I have a Weapon class defined as follows:

```
class Weapon
{
    public:
        Weapon(std::string type);
        Weapon(void);
        ~Weapon(void);

        void                setType(std::string type);
        std::string const   &getType(void) const;
    private:
        std::string _type;
};
```

And this human class:

```
class HumanA
{
    public:
        HumanA(std::string name, Weapon &Wp);
        ~HumanA(void);
        
        void        attack(void) const;
        void        setName(std::string name);
        void        setWeapon(Weapon Wp);
        std::string getName(void) const;
        Weapon      getWeapon(void) const;
    private:
        Weapon      &_weapon;
        std::string         _name;
};
```

The problem is that, when I call `getWeapon` from `HumanA`, the weapon destructor gets called every time.

Here is my main code:

```
int main()
{
    {
        Weapon club = Weapon("crude spiked club");
        HumanA bob("Bob", club);
        bob.attack(); <--- getWeapon function get used here 
        club.setType("some other type of club");
        bob.attack();
    }
        return (0);
}
```

And output would be like:

```
A weapon has been called.
A HumanA has been called.
Bob attacks with his crude spiked club
A weapon has been down. <------- And Here
Bob attacks with his some other type of club
A weapon has been down. <------- Here
HumanA has been backedoff.
A weapon has been down.
```

I don't know if this is normal but can anybody help explain this weird behaviour.

Comment: Your `getWeapon`  returns a copy - that copy has to be destroyed as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though you have defined the `_weapon` member of your `HumanA` class as a *reference* to a `Weapon`, the `getWeapon` function is declared as returning an actual `Weapon` *object* (by value); so, when called, it will make a copy of the `Weapon` object referenced by the member and return that – the copied object will be destroyed (and it's destructor called) when it goes out of context.

You should declare your `getWeapon` function as returning a *reference*, and then return (a copy of) the relevant human's `_weapon` member:

```cpp
Weapon& HumanA::getWeapon(void) const {
    return _weapon;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that made sense but what would it be if i was declaring the _weapon as a pointer? how should the getWeapon work?

Comment: @f0rkr That would depend on what you want it to do: you can either return that pointer or return a copy of the object pointed-to. That latter will gave the same 'issue' as your original code. If you you return a pointer, then any module that uses it would need to use `->` on it to access members.

Comment: @Andrian Mole Yeah that what i did and it reproduced the same behaviour as before. What i did to solve it is to return reference to the address pointed by that pointer. is that a good way to do it?
PS: i can't return the pointer directly because that what i was told in the project, means im not allowed to use -> on it to access members.

Comment: That's fine. If you have `Weapon *_weapon;` as the member, then you can just `return *_weapon;` in your getter; if that getter is defined as returning a reference, then that's what it will return (no object copy will be done).

Comment: @Andrian Mole with that behavior would we consider it bad practice? can it cause problems ?

Answer (score 1):

When returning an object by value, a **temporary** object is being created. Therefore, the desturctor will be called every time you call this function.